# IOException when convert HttpEntity into String

Tags: java, asp.net, io, tostring, apache-httpclient-4.x

I got a `IoException` When I try to parse http Entity from a ASP.NET api into string.

```
String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), responseCharset)
```

or

```
String responseBody =EntityUtils.toString((httpResponse.getEntity());
```

I try to do it by using these two method.They all works fine except the **ASP.NET api**,which can be requested normally with Postman.

I got the function which throw the exception when run at 'while' the second time.

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output, byte[] buffer)  throws IOException {
        long count = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (EOF != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
            count += n;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

The stack as follows:

> Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:268)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:227)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:137)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)  at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1928)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1907)    at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1884)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1834)     at
>   org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:705)

**The second way also failed when try to read buffer from a EofSensorInputStream**

*packages:
httpClient-4.5.1,
HttpCore-4.4.3,
Httpmine-4.5.1,
common-io-2.3.
  jdk:
1.8.0_65*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I got the function which throw the exception.The output got the string correctly,but throw a exception when run at 'while' the second time." can you update this piece of code

Comment: Thank you for your advise,I 've change the expression.